# WebLogic Portal & Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I have integrated spring portlet MVC 3.0 into Weblogic Portal 10.3. However, when I tried to activate multi-thread options in portlet, the maximized and minimized windows of portlets didn't run properly.

All my portlets are JavaPortlet as the configuration as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portal:root xmlns:netuix="http://www.bea.com/servers/netuix/xsd/controls/netuix/1.0.0" xmlns:portal="http://www.bea.com/servers/netuix/xsd/portal/support/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/servers/netuix/xsd/portal/support/1.0.0 portal-support-1_0_0.xsd">
    <netuix:javaPortlet definitionLabel="offshoreTechnology" offerRemote="false"
        forkable="true" forkPreRender="true" forkRender="true"
        portletName="offshoreTechnology" title="Offshore Technology">
        </netuix:javaPortlet>
</portal:root>
```

The **forkable="true" forkPreRender="true" forkRender="true"** will activate the multi-threading portlet.

Does anyone have such problem?

Comment: **forkable="true" forkPreRender="true" forkRender="true"**

Comment: hi abalogh, i'm struggling to setup the Spring portlet with weblogic 10.3. can you please share the sample project with me. my email is is dineshwije1990@gmail.com. thanks